# How to make the bracket smaller?

Tags: beamer, spacing, cases

The two big brackets are the same big, I dislike that. I want to keep the second one smaller, and let the space between the equation a little bit smaller. How could I do that? Thanks!

[image]

```
\documentclass[CJK]{beamer} 
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit} 
\usepackage{CJK,CJKnumb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{GBK}{song}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{
 Set\\$D=\left\{(x,y)\Big|,\begin{cases}
 2x-y=1 \\
 x+4y=5\\
 \end{cases}\right\}$
 }
 \end{frame}
 \end{CJK*}
```

\end{document}

Comment: Try `array` environment with `\bigg` (or other resize command)?

Comment: BTW, `CJK` is obsolete, try `xeCJK` with XeLaTeX or `LuaTeX-ja` with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Ch'enMeng  I'm used to use pdflatex now. Not familiar with XeLaTeX, may be it would be better. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, there is a new tech of supporting Chinese chars in LaTeX named zhmetrics put forward by Yuele Wang and consummate by Leo Liu. See [here](http://bbs.ctex.org/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=70222).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe with some additional justification, but the idea should be clear.

```
\documentclass[CJK]{beamer} 
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit} 
\usepackage{CJK,CJKnumb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{GBK}{song}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{
 %Set\\$D=\left\{(x,y)\Big|,\begin{cases}
Set\\$D=\left\{(x,y)\Big|,
\Bigl\{
\begin{array}{@{}r}
% 2x-y=1 \\
 2x-y=1 \\[-3pt] % as you wish
 x+4y=5\\
 %\end{cases}\right\}$
\end{array}\right\}$
 }
 \end{frame}
 \end{CJK*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `,` sign after `such that` vertical line is left, however it seems to be unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$
D =
\Bigg\{ 
    (x,y) \bigg|\,
    \bigg\{
        \!
        \begin{aligned}
            & 2x-y=1 \\
            & x+4y=5
        \end{aligned}
\Bigg\}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Smaller gap

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$
D =
\bigg\{ 
    (x,y) \Big|\,
    \Big\{
        \!
        \begin{aligned}
            & 2x-y=1 \\[-5pt]
            & x+4y=5
        \end{aligned}
\bigg\}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]